# Why in C++ do I need to pass a pointer by reference to change the pointed content?

Tags: c++, pointers, double-pointer

I am writing a function to load text from shader code file. I have stumbled upon something strange regarding pointers and I cannot figure out why.

I have a function named Load. In this function I copy text, taken from a file stream, in the **output** variable.

```
static void Load(const GLchar* source_path,  GLchar* output,GLint& count )
{
    string code;

    // loading logic here
    code= vShaderStream.str(); // copying the string from the stream
    count = code.length(); 
    output = new GLchar[count];
    std::size_t length = code.copy(output, count, 0);
    output[length]= '\0';
}
```

*Load* is called in this way:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < d_n_fragment; i++)
{
    Load(d_fragment_source_path, d_fragment_code[i], d_fragment_string_count[i]);
}
```

where **d_fragment_code** is a double pointer of Glchar** which is already initialized. After Load function is called the pointer **d_fragment_code[i]** contains no text. I tried to change the signature of the Load function to:

```
static void Load(const GLchar* source_path,  GLchar*& output,GLint& count )
```

and thus passing the pointer by reference. It works, after the function is called **d_fragment_code** holds correctly the text loaded from the file but I don't understand why a pointer it is to be passed by reference.

I thought that passing a pointer only would suffice to change its content. I am confused, could you shed some light on it?

Comment: You don't only change the content, you change the pointer here: `output = new GLchar[count];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass pointers by reference if you have to modify the pointer rather than the object that the pointer is pointing to.

Using double pointers is also a similar case.

Here is a more detailed article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> output = new GLchar[count];
> ```

This changes what `output` points to. If you are sure that `output` already points to a buffer of sufficient size, remove this line.

Comment: You didn't explain the problem or explain why we pass pointers by reference or explain why the fact that it was a pointer in the first place was insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that passing a pointer only would suffice to change its content.

Passing a pointer suffices to change the content of the pointee (the thing pointed to). That's great, and it has essentially the same effect as passing a reference.

But you're not doing that. You want to change the pointer itself.

Consider, if you wanted to pass an object into a function such that the function altered the original object. Let's call the object's type T, and let's pretend that it has a member function `mutate` that changes it somehow (so that we don't have to give a real-world example of this as `T` changes):

```
void foo(T& handle)
{
   handle.mutate();
}

void bar(T* handle)
{
   handle->mutate();
}

int main()
{
   T obj;
   foo(obj);
   bar(&obj);
}
```

Both `foo` and `bar` accomplish the same thing, using a reference and a pointer respectively.

Now we can apply this logic to anything, by exchanging various types for `T`. The scenario that *you're* thinking of, is passing some non-pointer object, by pointer, to mutate it:

```
void bar(int* handle)
{
   handle->mutate();
}

int main()
{
   int obj;
   bar(&obj);
}
```

But the situation you're *actually* in calls for `T` itself to be a pointer, and to use `foo` rather than `bar`. It's understandable that this is confusing!

```
void foo(GLint*& handle)
{
   handle.mutate();
}

int main()
{
   GLint* obj;
   foo(obj);
}
```

If it helps, you could also have written:

```
void bar(GLint** handle)
{
   handle->mutate();
}

int main()
{
   GLint* obj;
   bar(&obj);
}
```

which is effectively equivalent.

*(disclaimer: I didn't initialise `obj` in any of those examples. You'll want to.)*

Comment: You might want to point out *where* the OP is actually changing the pointer itself. It seems they're not aware.