# Passing and Assigning New Value to Pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, function-calls

I'm passing a pointer to a function.  I'd like to assign a new address to the passed pointer inside the function, and I'd like that address to be used after the function returns.  I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to do:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 100, j = 200;
    int * intPtr = &i;
    foo(intPtr, j);
    //  I want intPtr to point to j, which contains 200 after returning from foo.
}

void foo( int * fooPtr, int & newInt )
{
    int * newIntPtr = &newInt;
    fooPtr = newIntPtr;
}
```

Is this possible, or will `intPtr` not maintain the new assignment after returning from `foo`? Could this work (if it doesn't: why)?

Comment: Very confusing variable names.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28236527/560648

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a reference to the pointer:

`void foo( int *& fooPtr, int & newInt )`

The reason why your method does *not* work is that you're passing the pointer *by-value*.  Passing by-value creates a temporary within the function, so as soon as the function returns, any changes to the temporary go away.

It is no different than this:

```
void foo(int x)
{
   x = 10;
}

int main()
{
   int a = 0;
   foo( a );
   // a is still 0, not 10
}
```

The `a` is passed by value, so the `foo()` function changes the parameter to `10` within the function.  However, you will see that `a` in `main` does not change to 10 after the function returns.

To change `a`, you need to pass the `int` by reference:

```
void foo(int& x)
{
   x = 10;
}

int main()
{
   int a = 0;
   foo( a );
   // a is now 10
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass a pointer of the pointer and assign to it

```
int main()
{
    int i = 100, j = 200;
    int * intPtr = &i;
    foo( &intPtr, j );
    //  I want intPtr to point to j, which contains 200 after returning from foo.
}

void foo( int ** fooPtr, int & newInt )
{
    int * newIntPtr = newInt;
    *fooPtr = newIntPtr;
}
```

Comment: `int * newIntPtr = newInt;` has incompatible types

Comment: It looks like you have a typo: int * newIntPtr = &newInt;

Answer (score 1):

If you programing in pure C you can do like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(int **, int *);


 int main()
{
  int i = 100, j = 200;
  int * intPtr = &i;
  int  *intPtr2=&j;
  foo( &intPtr, intPtr2 );
  //  I want intPtr to point to j, which contains 200 after returning   from foo.
  printf("%d",*intPtr);
}
 void foo( int ** fooPtr, int * newInt )
{
  int * newIntPtr = newInt;

  *fooPtr = newIntPtr; 
}
```

Comment: I think this would assign the value 200 to the address pointed to by intPtr, but intPtr wouldn't point to j.  I need the address pointed to by intPtr to change in main.

Comment: I edited code, now you can change that this pointer point to j. I used pointer to pointer, and send the address of pointer in main. Above is exactly the same answer, so i hope this helps. Yes and you are right.