# Parameter both a pointer and reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, reference

I'm checking out an assignment, and I've just found this in a header file, which I have to fill up in a .cpp:

```
void setData(const component_t * & data_ptr); // Copy the data from data_ptr to the internal buffer. 
//The function ASSUMES a proper size for the incomming data array.
```

If you're wondering about *component_t*, it's a float through *typedef*.

So, my question is, what kind of parameter is *data_ptr*? How can it be defined both by * and & (both a pointer and reference?).

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: It is a reference to a pointer.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510101/passing-and-assigning-new-value-to-pointer-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `data_ptr` is a reference to a pointer to a `const component_t`.

In C and C++, a pointer isn't really special. It's just a number that points to an address in memory. Usually when you pass a `T*` as a parameter, you are passing *by value*; that is, the number representing the memory address is just copied, the same as if you passed an `int` by value.

In this case, you are passing a `T*&`, or reference-to-pointer-to-T. But it works in much the same way as if you passed an `int&`, or reference to `int`: it means that you're allowed to change the referenced object.

So in this case you could say, for example

```
void setData(const component_t * & data_ptr)
{
    data_ptr = new component_t(/* args... */);
}
```

although this is not necessarily a good way to do things in modern C++.

Comment: Thanks for this . I would use a ten foot long pole to measure the distance and stay away from this ;) But is there a place where is this is particular useful where we cannot do things without it?

Comment: @sjsam `int readint(char *& bufp) {int x = *bufp++; x <<= 8; x |= *bufp++; x <<= 8; x |= *bufp++; x <<= 8; x |= *bufp++; return x;}` or something like that. It iterates through a buffer updating the pointer to the buffer while building an `int`. At the end, you have the assembled `int` and bufp is pointing to the next location after the `int` in the buffer.

Comment: Thanks Tristan. Appreciate this.

Comment: Great answer and clarifications Tristan. Thank you a lot mate. :)