# Modifying pointer to string literal in separate function

Tags: c++, constants, string-constant

I have what is hopefully a trivial question that someone can explain to me in simpler terms than what I have already come across.  While working through

> A Tour of C++ (Second Edition)

I've been trying a few examples.

I'm currently trying to modify a pointer to a string literal in a separate function (I thought it would be easy.....).

```
using namespace std;

void test(char *ptr)
{
    ptr = "test";
}

int main()
{
    char *p = "abc";
    test(p);
    cout << p << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When using g++ to compile, I get a

> Warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to char*

Apparently g++ is auto-converting *p to a const?  Surely I'm missing something basic, but my previous SO and google searches have gotten me no closer to the answer.  Thank you for your responses!

EDIT:
Both great examples below.  Thank you everyone for your responses, very helpful!

Comment: String literals are always `const char[]` (or some other character type depending on the literal's prefix). In c++ you may not assign a string literal to a `char*`. For a while it was permitted for compatibility reasons but that exemption has been removed from the language. You may never modify string literals, and that has always been true.

Comment: Even if this did compile, your results would still not be reflected back to the caller.  `p` would still point to "abc" after the call to `test`.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510101/passing-and-assigning-new-value-to-pointer-c).  So you have two issues, the first is the `const`-ness issue, and the second is one of passing a pointer and believing that changing the value of the pointer within a function changes the passed-in pointer's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apparently g++ is auto-converting *p to a const?

Quite the opposite. The string `"abc"` will be in your binary, and that is supposed to be readonly for your program. Therefore, that string should only be read, and the value you get when assigning the string literal in this situation is of type `const char*`. You get the error because you're assigning it to a non-const `char*`. Try this instead:

```
const char *p = "abc";
```

Also, you'll have to change the function, too:

```
void test(const char *ptr)
{
    ptr = "test";
}
```

It's still going to print `abc`, however. That's because you're only modifying a copy of the value that you're passing. But C++ lets you pass a reference instead, which you can do like this:

```
void test(const char *&ptr)
{
    ptr = "test";
}
```

Now that's a reference to a pointer pointing to a `const char`... whew! Both the `"abc"` and `"test"` will be in the program's binary when it is compiled. When the program is run, the address of `"abc"` is assigned to `char *p`, and then the function to change it to have the address of `"test"` instead is called. The `&` tells it to work with the actual `char *p` and not just a copy of it that gets lost when the function finishes.

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense and your example does get it to compile.  However, is my understanding correct that any string literal initialized as const char *X will be read-only throughout it's life?  Edit: yes, const is...well....constant ;)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux haha yep, I just noticed it. I added a version where we pass a reference instead.

Comment: @user3541502 `const` literals are the only kinds of literals. You could get a mutable string by using `char p[] = "abc";`.

Comment: @user3541502 The syntax is a bit confusing here. `const char*` is NOT const. It's a non-const pointer pointing to a `const char`. `char* const` is a const pointer pointing to a non-const `char` and `const char* const` is a const pointer pointing to a `const char`.

Comment: @Blaze Ahh!  That makes sense.  So in your example above, *&ptr is actually allocating a different section of memory and changing the pointer to point at a different string literal (which is constant)?

Comment: Actually, both the `"abc"` and `"test"` will already be in your program's binary when it is compiled. When you run the program, you're assigning the address of `"abc"` to `char *p`, and then you call the function to change it to have the address of `"test"` instead. The `&` tells it to work with the actual  `char *p` and not just a copy of it that gets lost when the function finishes.

Comment: @Blaze That comment answered the root of my problem with understanding.  Would you mind adding that to the bottom of your post?  Thank you very much for your help, definitely much clearer now!!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that can be `const`; the pointer (`char * const`), or the object (`const char *`).

The string literal is `const`, that's what the compiler is complaining about. You should use

```
const char *p = "abc";
```

The function would still not modify the pointer `p` from `main()` though, because it is passed by value to the function.

This should modify the pointer:

```
using namespace std;
const char * str2 = "test";    

void test(const char *& ptr)
{
    ptr = str2;
}

int main()
{
    const char *p = "abc";
    test(p);
    cout << p << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1588ea324031af16)